# How to prove to the management the futility of saving IDE specific files in GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github, intellij-idea, version-control, gitlab

I can not prove to the management the futility and even harm of saving IDE specific files and folders in GitHub

There is even a problem in the deliberate mixing of two different issues:

- I want to use Eclipse;
- If we use Eclipse, then its files should be stored in the repository;

I tried everything:

- from "files not related to the project should not be there"
- to "every developer knows how to configure their IDE for the project based on the pom.xml"
- and "if two programmers use two different IDEs, should their files also be saved?"
- and so on... like "specially designed gitignore.io provides recommended gitignore based on what you are using."

What arguments can be given besides “no one does that for a long time because it's obvious”.

PS. I am not going to start another holy war, I need arguments that are clear to the management.

Comment: The [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is not *do not share IDE-specific files*, but **as long as tool-specific files are maintained**, they **should be shared**, even if they are not used by everyone.

This applies to specific files of GitHub, Jenkins, FindBugs/SpotBugs, Eclipse and other tools. The presence of these files does not harm (files and folders starting with a dot meant to be hidden). This is well documented (e.g. [here for Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_advantage_of_sharing_the_project_file_in_a_repository%3F)) and after all, the tools do not place these files in the project directory for no reason, although it would be possible otherwise, but because they are meant to be shared.

However, there are still people who believe that there should be one Maven-specific `pom.xml` file only, which is focused on building only. But since none of them is a tool developer and none of them has never convinced the tool developers, it is very unlikely that you will convince your management.

Also be aware that Eclipse-specific files are not specific to the Eclipse IDE, as they are also used by e.g. VS Code. Eclipse-specific are not even IDE-specific, since, for example, the Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj) can be used as a linter inside a build to run on a server.